# Flutter share - is there any way to know share functionality completion?

Tags: flutter, share

i'm trying to implement analytics for share event in my flutter app. Find my code below, it execute immediately after share window ui appear. 
But i need to track logEvent only after share complete successfully. is there any way to know  share functionality completion in flutter?

```
    Share.share(_deepLinkUrl).then((onValue) {
      print("share completion block ");
      analytics.logEvent(
          name: 'share',
          parameters: <String, dynamic>{});
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `whenComplete()` from `Future` class. However `whenComplete` doesn't take argument.

```
Share.share(_deepLinkUrl).whenComplete(() {
      print("share completion block ");
      analytics.logEvent(
          name: 'share',
          parameters: <String, dynamic>{});
     })
```